# Quebra de linha não está ocorrendo ao exceder tamanho do container

Tags: html, css

Tenho um paginator dentro de um container-fluid, acontece que como o paginator tem muitas páginas, ele não está realizando a quebra de linha, acontecendo isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei aplicar na minha div:

```
word-wrap: break-word!important;
white-space: normal!important;
```

Meu paginator:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav *ngIf="logs != null" aria-label="pagination example" class="pagination">
      <ul class="pagination pg-blue">
        <li [class.disabled]="paginaatual == 1" class="page-item">
          <p (click)="consultaLogs(paginaatual - 1)" class="page-link" aria-label="Anterior">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
          </p>
        </li>
        <li (click)="consultaLogs(numpagina+1)" [class.active]="numpagina+1 == paginaatual" *ngFor="let numpagina of numbers"
          class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link">{{numpagina + 1}}<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li [class.disabled]="paginaatual == numpaginas" class="page-item">
          <a (click)="consultaLogs(paginaatual+1)" class="page-link next" aria-label="Proximo">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Proximo</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="col-5">
          <input type="text" #numeropaginas [disabled]="numpaginas == 1" [class.danger]="numeropaginas.value > numpaginas"
            (keyup.enter)="consultaLogs(numeropaginas.value)" placeholder="Nro.Pág" id="inputnropag" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Nada acontece.
Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: você leu minha publicação inteira? a resposta do cara eu já tentei!

Comment: Depois do número 8 coloca a tag `<wbr>` e veja se funciona, se der certo me fala que te dou uma resposta com mais detalhes.